# How can I test the alignment of my form?

Tags: selenium, junit, junit4

I use Selenium and JUnit4, and I have a form which I want to test for correct alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use methods `getLocation().x` and `getLocation().y` of a WebElement.

For example

```
int id1X = driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).getLocation().x; 
int id2X = driver.findElement(By.id("id2")).getLocation().x;
assertEquals(id1X, id2X);
```

to verify vertical alignment.
You can also play with `getSize().height` and `getSize().width` to have more complex conditions.

Comment: I used this example but I do not know is this-that it works or not

Comment: What are id1x and id2x ?

Comment: @prab2112 those are the values of the horizontal locations of each respective element. The name doesn't matter.